# Как изменить цвет в графике (R)

Tags: r

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить на цвет к примеру вместо зелёного на голубой а в место красного на оранжевый

```
#lets plot some graphs and see relations or patterns
ggplot(df,aes(x=DiabetesPedigreeFunction,y=Insulin)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(aes(color=Outcome))
ggplot(df,aes(x=BloodPressure,y=Insulin)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(aes(color=Outcome))
ggplot(df,aes(x=Age,y=Insulin)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point(aes(color=Outcome))
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'

`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "green",
                               "0" = "orange"))
```